# UI not listing contents of Eclipse software site

Tags: eclipse, p2, pde, target-platform

When trying to add a Software Site (p2 plugin repository - either
  one generated by p2 Publisher or Nexus with p2 support) to a target 
  definition via the "Target Definition Wizard" there seem to be "no items
  available" preventing the site to be added.

The same problem has been reported e.g. here: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Nexus/Nexus+OSGi+Experimental+Features+-+P2+Repository+Plugin?focusedCommentId=12943363#comment-12943363

Tycho and the https://github.com/ifedorenko/p2-browser are capable of
  fetching the metadata and contents though, since the site contains a 
  number of bundles (in "plugins" dir) along with artifacts.xml and content.xml.

Is there a known limitation/bug of the UI related to this behaviour or 
  could you please point me to a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the UI shows only "categorized" features. Uncheck the checkbox to see all features in the repository.

Comment: Thanks. (Un)selecting the checkbox does not influence the display still missing the artifacts. But you are refering to "features". What is deployed are uncategorized plug-ins/OSGi bundles only. We plan to use the same P2 repo for Tycho and PDE Target definition..

Comment: The user interface in question is restricted to features. It does not display bundles.